# Undestanding p-value and '***'

Tags: r, scientific-notation, p-value, significant-digits

I have a dilemma regarding significance in [r](/questions/tagged/r). I don't really understand something.
For example if I have:

[image]

Does it show a significant relationship? Because the [p-value](/questions/tagged/p-value) seems to be greater than 0.05, but actually there are "***". Hope you can make me understand that. I'am not that familiar with [Tag:R,] I used to work with `SPSS`, it wasn't actually like here. Thanks!

Comment: The p value is _much_ less than 0.05 here. This is scientific notation, so 1.01e-14 means 1.01 * 10^(-14) or 0.0000000000000101.

Comment: Oh, ok, so actually this is said by "e-" ?

Comment: Thank you very much, so that's why *** are there. Thank you!

Comment: the `e` means exponent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default R uses the scientific notation. For example, p-value of 0.05 will be represented as 5e-2 (you can type it in console).

You can change the default by typing `options(scipen = 999)`.
In addition, you can set the number of digits to round automatically using `options(digits = 3)`.

For a very easy to understand explanation on how scientific notation works, you can look [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/scientific-notation.html).

Comment: I get it now, forever, finally :)). Thank you!

Comment: That's ok, I was also confused by this for some time :)